# Consuming flex3 components in Visual Composer 7.2 using Web Dynpro

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, webdynpro

Is there a way to export table data to a MIME Resource (Flex3 component) from Web Dynpro?

I have a flex3 component (US heat Map) which accepts an array Collection (state and value pairs). I need to create a Web Dynpro wrapper for this to use in Visual Composer 7.2.

What I am trying to do is migrate the flex components I made for Visual Composer 7.0 (using a VCXL wrapper) to Visual Composer 7.2 using Web Dynpro. I have managed to migrate components which require simple input data types like integer or string, but I am stuck at those which require complex structures like an array collection.

For those who are well versed with VCXL specifications, I am looking for an equivalent of "ArrayPort" in Web Dynpro.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Still waiting for any useful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.dev-trend.com/main/?tag=flex-30) mentions there can be data conversion issues when converting data of simple types.  I recommend passing all data via arraycollections to convert complex data.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Downvoting because its totally out of context. This answer is not at all helpful. The link that you mentioned tells the flex handling of SAP web dynpro request which I already knew.

My question was how to write web dynpro code to pass complex data types and not how to handle it in flex. Total waste of my precious reputation points.